# Adding Ints in a UILabel in Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am making an app where there is a football field and when you click on the Score Zone 7 points are added to the `UILabel` that marks score. But I have only been able to display a 7 once and if I click again the seven appears again; I want it to add 7 more to make a 14.

```
@IBAction func touchdownMD(sender: AnyObject) {
    var pointsMD = Int()
    scoreMD.text = "\(pointsMD + 7)"
}

@IBOutlet var scoreSH: UILabel!
```

[image]

Comment: pointsMD is initialised whenever the function is called, so you always start from 0, try declaring a class level variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `pointsMD` inside of the `touchdownMD:` function, it starts from 0 whenever the function is called.

In order to fix this, you need to declare it at the class level. For example:

```
var pointsMD = Int() //initialize pointsMD at the class level

@IBAction func touchdownMD(sender: AnyObject){
  pointsMD+=7 //add 7 to pointsMD
  scoreMD.text = "\(pointsMD)"
}
```

That way, `pointsMD` will not reset whenever `touchdownMD:` is called, it will instead just increment as needed.

So, here's what your code could look like:

```
var pointsMD = Int()

@IBAction func touchdownMD(sender: AnyObject) {
  pointsMD+=7
  scoreMD.text = "\(pointsMD)"
}

@IBOutlet var scoreSH: UILabel!
```